# Facebook webhook feed - not receiving shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I have subscribed my facebook app to receive webhook updates on feed and it works great with posts, likes and comments. However, I'm not receiving post shares at my endpoint even though facebook docs states that the feed subscription also includes share (Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page --> feed section).

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: What kind of shares are you talking about - posts by others, shared by the page on its timeline; or other people sharing your page’s posts elsewhere? (Your app doesn’t get to see users sharing your page’s posts on their own timelines, unless those users had also granted your app user_posts permission on their end, of course.)

Comment: Thx .. yeah I was asking about users sharing posts from my page and i want to reward them .. but as you said it seems not applicable unless I have an app and I let the user give me the "user_posts" permission

Comment: You are not allowed to reward users for sharing. https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5) _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_

Comment: Thx .. but I actually don't get it .. if I'm making an app (a game for example) and I want to promote a contest and reward the people who share my contest post with some in-app items, what's the harm?

Comment: It creates spam - stuff people would not otherwise posts, if their was no reward tied to it.